Keytab File configration at Spark ReadStream from Kafka format
Dears,
Iam Tring to consume from kafka using spark.readStream.format("kafka") but every time i got an error of
**Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /data01/ekeid/kafka.client.keystore.jks of type JKS**
****even I built Nifi job to consume and point to the same keystore file at the same location and it consume and subscribe successfully without any errors, so why Spark gets me this error every time. **
**
config_dic = {
        
    "kafka.group.id": "bdp.qradarG19092024_0",
        "kafka.security.protocol": "SSL",
      ##  "kafka.ssl.keystore.location":"file:///data01/ekeid/keystore.jks",
      ##  "kafka.ssl.keystore.location":"hdfs:///tmp/ekeid/qradar/kafka/keystore.jks",
         "kafka.ssl.keystore.location":"/data01/ekeid/kafka.client.keystore.jks",

        "kafka.ssl.keystore.password": "cloudera",
        "kafka.ssl.key.password": "cloudera",
    "kafka.bootstrap.servers": bootstrap_servers,
        "subscribe": subscribe_Topics
    }
   spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DualEdgeStream").config(conf=conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate() 
   streamk_lines =  spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").options(**config_dic).load()

 
    json_data = streamk_lines.select(F.from_json(streamk_lines.value.cast("string"), schema).alias("parsed_value"))   

    query = json_data.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()
    query.awaitTermination()


enter image description here
I tried every thing and always nifi can read the file as usual but spark always can't see the file despite it's existence.
type here

